# Difference between train.Age.mean() and train['Age'].mean() in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a pandas dataframe called train and it has a column called Age. What is the difference between method 1 and method 2.

```
avg1 = train.Age.mean() 
avg2 = train['Age'].mean()
```

Comment: No difference, so long as `Age` is not a property of the dataframe (which it is not in this case). Also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/in-a-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-d

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, that duplicate is much more appropriate.