# How do I convert a Pandas Dataframe with one column into a Pandas Dataframe of two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a single column that contains States followed by their particular regions. The states are already in alphabetical order. I want to convert this single column into two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
places = [{'State':'Alabama'},{'State':'Auburn'},{'State':'Florence'},{'State':'Troy'},{'State':'Alaska'},{'State':'Fairbanks}]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(places)

s1 = df0.loc[df['State']=='Alabama'].index[0] #return row of state 'Alabama'
s2 = df0.loc[df['State']=='Alaska'].index[0]  #return row of state 'Alaska'
df1 = df0                                     # create new dataframe

for index, row in df0.iterrows():             # parse single column into two columns data
    if index == s1:
        df1['State']='Alabama'
    elif index <= s2:
        df1['Region']=row['State']
df
```

The above code returns:

```
     State    Region
0    Alabama   Alabama
1    Alabama   Alabama
...  ...       ...
500  Alabama   Alabama
```

Note: In my example I only use Alabama and Alaska but there are another 500 rows below this for the other states. Any idea how I can get to the following:

```
     State     Region
0    Alabama   Auburn
1    Alabama   Florence
2    Alabama   Troy
3    Alaska    Fairbanks
...  ...       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to have all the data for states: It will be good if you download it and call the states. I will manually try to call it over here by the first few lines

```
#This is not necessary. Download the file and call states directly from it.
import re
import pandas as pd
a = 'http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577305-python-dictionary-of-us-states-and-territories/download/1/'
states = eval(re.sub("(?<=\w')\s+(?=[^:])",",","".join(['{']+list(pd.read_csv(a).index))))
```

Just run this code as it is and do `print(states)` see whether you have all the states in your IDE
You can also directly copy paste it as `states` from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577305-python-dictionary-of-us-states-and-territories/)

Now that we have all the states we can solve the problem

```
import numpy as np

places = [{'State':'Alabama'},{'State':'Auburn'},{'State':'Florence'},{'State':'Troy'},{'State':'Alaska'},{'State':'Fairbanks'}]

df0 = pd.DataFrame(places)
df0['Regions'] = df0.State

B = pd.DataFrame(df0.set_index('Regions').State.replace(regex=f'^(?!({"|".join(states.values())})).*',value=np.nan).reset_index()).ffill()
B[B.State!=B.Regions].iloc[:,[1,0]]

     State    Regions
1  Alabama     Auburn
2  Alabama   Florence
3  Alabama       Troy
5   Alaska  Fairbanks
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer works. If you have time could you (1) explain what the replace statement is doing? (2) Why I need to use reset_index()? And when you call df.State are you just calling the column directly? So df['State'] == df.State?

Comment: @Riskinit 1. is`df['State'] == df.State`? yes. read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/in-a-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-d). 2 `reset_index()`. Technically it depends on how you solve the question. You will realize that I did set the `Regions` to be the indices, so I am undoing the process. I did not want to concatenate. You can decide not to set and reset.

Comment: @Riskinit 3.replace is just selecting all those that are not states and replacing them with `np.nan`. I am using `regular expressions`. So I first join all the states as `Alabama|Alaska|.....` then claim `^(?!...).*` which is a negative forward reference. It was easy in this case since the states were at the beginning of each sentence. You could have actually used `f'^((?!({"|".join(states.values())})).)*$'` which is generalized. you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)