# df.date_column_name showing different output compared to df['date_column_name']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, numpy-ndarray

so I tried creating a new column name using df.column_name convention like here:

```
df2.DATE_CLOSED_calc= np.where(np.isnat(df2.DATE_CLOSED),np.datetime64('today'),df2.DATE_CLOSED)
```

but I got user warning, hence using recommendation by @AaronDT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344256/7027147), I just used df2['DATE_CLOSED_calc'] instead of df2.DATE_CLOSED_calc, then I didn't get a warning.

But what surprised is when I looked at df2.DATE_CLOSED_calc:

> array([None, None, None, ..., None, None, None], dtype=object)

but df2['DATE_CLOSED_calc'] shows :

[image]

I always thought df.column_name or df['column_name'] referred to same column as Pandas series. Isn't that true? Why isn't it the case here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: afaik you're only supposed to use the dot accessor for accessing the data, not assigning it.

Comment: It is probably because you alread assigned something to it in your code, probably in the line you showed on top. Try to restart your IDE and remove all the assign to that column, it should give the correct result.

Comment: @molybdenum42 indeed, but now that I assigned df.column_name in one way and df['column_name'] in another way, can't I use df.column_name to access column of the data anymore, unless I change original assignment?

Comment: @Erfan I know I assigned something different, I know I can get what I want by specifying df['column_name'] instead of df.column_name. Question is more philosophical about how df.column_name changes its behaviour when it is used to assign instead of access

Comment: Have read in the link above.

Comment: @BharatRamAmmu my understanding is that with the assignment you set a new attribute of the dataframe to that numpy array. This new attribute now overwrites the column accessor.