# Python operator overloading in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, operator-overloading

There is [operator overloading in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python). In the official documentation there is a [list of operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators).

However in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), `[]`  and `.`, which are not present in list of operators in the previous link, are also called operators.

> Note The Python and NumPy indexing operators `[]` and attribute operator
>    `.` provide quick and easy access to pandas data structures across a
>   wide range of use cases.

Are `[]` and `.` operators in Python?  Can they be, and are they overloaded in Pandas?

Comment: bit of info here...my personal opinion is to just always use []

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/for-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-do

Comment: Why are you looking at docs for Python **2.0**? :o We're at 2.7 and 3.7. You're looking at 18-year-old stuff! `June 22, 2001
Release 2.0.1` How did you even find it?

Comment: `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, and if you need it: `__delitem__` https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @h4z3 in asnwer by "Cong Ma" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method "The [] syntax for getting item by key or index is just syntax sugar." Do you agree or not?

Comment: @h4z3, in the link both get and set are for []. What about dot?

Comment: @h4z3 good catch! I have amended my edit, it was only visual, I've updated the  link as well, after checking in 3 version I could not see [] either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [] and . (dot) are in next section of user docs: `2.6. Delimiters`

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

AFAIK these are not formally operators and cannot be overloaded. As for their actual use in pandas you are welcome to see for yourself in the link you youself posted:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html.