# Attribute vs dict notation for referencing pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Are the following two items equivalent?

```
df['studio'] == df.studio
```

I thought that it would return a `True/False` based on a comparison of the entire object, but when doing this, it seems to return another `pd.Series` with a bunch of `True/False` values so it's hard (for me at least) to tell if the two items are the same thing or not.

If they are the same, is one notation preferred over another? If they are not, how are the two different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/for-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-do. `.`. a is convenience method and has several pitfalls/limitations, so brackets are generally better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['studio']` and `df.studio` are the same thing. However, `df['studio']` is preferred because:

- Indexing (such as slicing) uses the 'bracket notation' ( [ ]'s )
- Using bracket notation is much more common and universal among languages and lets other developers read your code easier

I'm assuming when you ran `df['studio'] == df.studio` you got a series of `True True True` etc.

That's because you are comparing the studio column, to the studio column.
You could also do the following:
`df[df['studio'] == df['studio']]`

which returns all of the rows (instead of True/False), essentially saying:
Return to me all the rows where the `studio` column is equivalent to the `studio` column (which, of course, is always.)