# Substitute values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns(A,B,C). I wanted to update column `C` with column `A` when column `B`=22. I have written update statement like this, but it's updating `NaN` for non matching rows. Could you tell me how to update data in dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10,20,30],[11,21,31],[12,22,32]], columns=['A','B','C'])
df.C = df[df.B==22].A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `mask`

```
df.C.mask(df.B==22, df.A,inplace=True)
df
    A   B   C
0  10  20  30
1  11  21  31
2  12  22  12
```

Comment: Series.mask is definitely more intuitive than Series.where.

Answer (score 3):

One of several ways to do this, and yes it requires an additional package, but if you aren't aware of `np.where` it's pretty handy.

```
import numpy as np

df['C'] = np.where(df['B']==22, df['A'], df['C'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[df.B==22, 'C'] = df.loc[df.B==22, 'A']
```

Comment: I would probably use `.loc` on the *right-hand-side* also.

Comment: If you have unique indexes you can use only `df['A']` on the right-hand-side

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using `loc` and `reindex`:

```
df['C'] = df.loc[df.B==22,'A'].reindex(df.index).fillna(df['C'])
```

---

Ideally you can use `np.where` for such cases, however here is why your code doesnot work:

The below

```
df[df.B==22].A
```

Returns:

```
2    12
```

you will see that the index of the returned values is `2`, so when you set `df.C` ([*use bracket notation instead of a `.` notation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/for-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-do)) , it updates the series named `C` to the result of previous which does not contain the other indexes (but only 2) , hence other indexes are set as `np.nan`

Also it is highly discouraged to use [`chained indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) when assigning values as it leads to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) warning.