# Filters in Pandas - why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This is a basic question so apologies in advance.

I am using Pandas and I am grouping data with the following line:

```
page_serp_df.groupby([page_serp_df.meta_keywords_1_length]).count()['keyword']
```

This is referencing the following:

- The data frame: **[page_serp_df]**
- Grouping by the column: **meta_keywords_1_length**
- Counting with the filter: **keyword** column

What I don't understand is why does the filtering condition have to be **['keyword']** i.e. a string in quotes?
For example, this doesn't work and it is very counterintuituve to me:

```
page_serp_df.groupby([page_serp_df.meta_keywords_1_length]).count()[page_serp_df.keyword]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's not the right way to create a filter to groupby, think of it this way, you group your entire result set (the dataframe) select the column OR condition to apply your group by too, then select your target column with a specific type of aggregation. Is keyword a column or a variable in a column you need to filter by ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. 'Keyword' is a column.

Comment: try `page_serp_df.groupby([page_serp_df['meta_keywords_1_length']])['keyword'].count()`

Comment: So I guess that is where I am struggling conceptually: the difference between the dot-notation (i.e. page_serp_df.meta_keywords_1_length) and the square bracket (i.e. [page_serp_df['meta_keywords_1_length']]). What is the difference and which is best practice?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/for-pandas-dataframe-whats-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding on what the `.count()` method returns.

Try to follow this example:

#### Create a sample data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[0,1,0,1, 1],
    'B':[100,200,300, 400, 500],
    'C': [1,2,3,4,5]
})
```

#### This is what the `count()` method will return after `groupby`

```
# similarly to your example I am grouping by A and counting 
df.groupby([df.A]).count()
```

[image]

As you can see, the `count()` method returns a dataframe itself, having the count of each other column values for the column where the grouped column has the same value.
After that, you can query for a specific column form the return of `count()` like this

```
df.groupby([df.A]).count()['C']
```

But the second case in your example, which in my example would correspond to `df.groupby([df.A]).count()[df.C]`

Will throw an error!

[image]

In fact, you would query a dataframe (in this case `df.groupby([df.A]).count()`) via a pandas `Series` but as you know you need a string or a column from `df.columns`.

You can check yourself that `df.C` and `'C'` are two very different variable types.

```
print(type(df.C))
print(type('C'))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'str'>
```

If for some reason your code still works with the equivalent of `df.C` there might be some contingency like the only value of the `df.C` is a string with the same name of a column.. or something unintentional like that.