# Combine np arrays in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
cars= pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]],
                    'y': [[8,9,7],[9,8,1],[3,4,1]]})

       x          y
0  [1, 2, 3]  [8, 9, 7]
1  [2, 3, 4]  [9, 8, 1]
2  [5, 6, 7]  [3, 4, 1]
```

I want this:

```
      x          y            combined
0  [1, 2, 3]  [8, 9, 7]  [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 7]
1  [2, 3, 4]  [9, 8, 1]  [2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1]
2  [5, 6, 7]  [3, 4, 1]  [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1]
```

I have tried this, and it does not work:

```
cars['combined']=pd.concat([cars['x'],cars['y']])
cars['combined']=cars['x'].append(cars['y'])
cars['combined']=pd.concat((cars['x'],cars['y']),axis=0)
cars['combined']=cars['x'].join(cars['y'])
```

How do I combine these?

Comment: probably dirty: `cars[['x','y']].sum(1)`

Comment: That works very well if I only had 2 columns, In my case I will have a lot of columns before I add them.

Comment: Well then change the subset `cars[['x','y','other_col','more_col']].sum(1)`

Comment: you can also make  use `df.columns` attribute and indexing if you had very much columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:-

```
cars['combined']=cars['x']+cars['y']
```

Now if you print `cars` you will get your desired output:

```
    x               y        combined
0   [1, 2, 3]   [8, 9, 7]   [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 7]
1   [2, 3, 4]   [9, 8, 1]   [2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1]
2   [5, 6, 7]   [3, 4, 1]   [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Works very well, and I am familiar with this notation.

Comment: It's the better way then accessing columns by `.` notation

Comment: @AnuragDabas Why?

Comment: In my real data I have a Series with ndarray generated from an apply comand. The apply  comand gave me a Series with ndarray, just like in my simplified question. I get the "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (3,)" error. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: yes the shape of arrays are different so due to this  you are getting this error

Comment: @pakpe kindly have a look on https://www.dataschool.io/pandas-dot-notation-vs-brackets/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/what-is-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-dot-to-access-a-column

Comment: @AnuragDabas I did. None of those issues apply to this question. When it is possible to use dot notation, it provides for a much cleaner code that’s faster to write.

Comment: @pakpe Yeah you are right...I am saying this generally not only for this question....apart from advantage and disadvantage...it's per the convience of user some likes bracket notation and some like dot notation as it is provides a much cleaner code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
cars['combined'] = cars.x + cars.y
print(cars)

           x          y            combined
0  [1, 2, 3]  [8, 9, 7]  [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 7]
1  [2, 3, 4]  [9, 8, 1]  [2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 1]
2  [5, 6, 7]  [3, 4, 1]  [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Works very welll. Thank you.