# Propagation in Python - Pandas Series TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, square-root

I am trying to propagate uncertainty in Python by adding two columns together of a Pandas data frame and then taking the square root. However, when I try to use Python's `math.sqrt` function, I receive a `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`.

Here is what I've been doing:

```
joinedDF['combined_error'] = math.sqrt((joinedDF.error1**2 + joinedDF.error2**2).astype(float))
```

Using `joinedDF.dtypes`, I've verified that both error columns are `float64`.

I've even tried seperating everything out, but I still receive a TypeError. Any suggestions about how to mend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come to mind.

Option 1: use `numpy.sqrt`:

```
import numpy as np

joinedDF['combined_error'] = np.sqrt((joinedDF['error1']**2 +
                                      joinedDF['error2']**2))
```

Option 2: if you want/need to avoid numpy for some reason, you can `apply` `math.sqrt` to the numeric column. This is likely slower than Option 1, but works in my testing:

```
   joinedDF['combined_error'] = (joinedDF['error1']**2 + 
                                 joinedDF['error2']**2).apply(math.sqrt)
```

Minor style comment: it's generally recommended to refer to DataFrame columns using indexing (square brackets) rather than attribute access (dot notation), so I modified your code accordingly. More reading: [What is the difference between using squared brackets or dot to access a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/what-is-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-dot-to-access-a-column)

Comment: are there any good slightly faster options?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend `numpy.sqrt`, since it's vectorized and forms the basis of pandas!