# Are there differences in performance/ is it best practice to use pandas dataframe attributes when referencing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I frequently go back and forth between using dataframe object attributes to refer to columns as well as using the bracket method.

I am wondering which format is considered "best practice," and if there are any performance differences between the two (or could this potentially vary based upon the circumstance?). I am not finding many resources on this subject.

Here's a simplistic example of what I mean: creating the column "green," with rows being True if columns "blue" and "yellow" are True, otherwise the rows are false.

```
# using brackets.
df['green'] = np.where((df['blue']==True) & (df['yellow']==True), True, False)
```

*vs.*

```
# using periods.
df['green'] = np.where((df.blue==True) & (df.yellow == True), True, False)
```

I often find myself using the latter as it looks cleaner, is shorter, and is easier to type. However, I often see pandas examples here and other sources using both methods.

- Is there a performance difference in using either format?
- Which format is considered best practice?

Comment: The most common issue I've seen on here: Consider a dataframe `df` with columns `df['name']` and `df['shape']`. Saving 4 characters of typing will _really_ screw you up when you start setting /changing the dataframe's `name` attribute instead of making changes to the `'name'` column, or throwing errors when trying to change the default behavior of `df.shape`. IMO always always use the brackets for column access

Comment: See also [What is the difference between using squared brackets or dot to access a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/what-is-the-difference-between-using-squared-brackets-or-dot-to-access-a-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no performance difference between the 2 notations:

- `df.blue` uses `__getattr__` to lookup the right column
- `df['blue']` uses `__getitem__` to lookup the right column (or index)

You need to have a valid python identifier if you want to use the first form and you can't use column name like `shape`, `size`, `values` and so on.

The second form is more explicit and it used by the `LocIndexer`. It allows you to use column name like `2022` or `Energy (KWH)`. I clearly prefer this notation.

Answer (score 2):

If performance matters, don't use where or similar costly function. A classic mask will do the job. Using `timeit` can give you an idea about your time consumption :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'yellow' : np.random.randint(0, 2, n),
                   'blue' : np.random.randint(0, 2, n)}, dtype = np.bool8)

%timeit np.where((df['blue']==True) & (df['yellow']==True), True, False)
252 µs ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit np.where((df.blue==True) & (df.yellow == True), True, False)
245 µs ± 3.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit df['blue'] & df['yellow']
72.1 µs ± 4.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit df.blue & df.yellow
77.1 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

In term of performance it's quite equivalent, and statically, you can't differentiate the two approach. In fact, in a costly implementation (as where for instance), the real bottleneck are not on how to access element.

Regarding the syntax, I prefer using .loc or .iloc to access elements since I find it more "pandas-ic", but that's totally up to you.